# How do I take a mongodb json to flask to react?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, flask, pymongo

So I want to take my mongo db and use it in react, its small so it won't overpower react. My Flask looks like this

```
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pymongo

disaster = ""
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)


client = pymongo.MongoClient("NOT IMPORTANT FOR GITHUB")
db = client["twitterdb"]
col = db["tweets"] 
our_mongo_database_compressed = col.find({},{'user.created_at':1, 'user.location':1,'_id':0}) 


def request_tweets(disaster):
    print(disaster)
    #subprocess.call("./../../../backend/get_tweets", disaster)

@app.route('/refresh_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def refresh_data():
    disaster = request.get_json()
    request_tweets(disaster)
    x = 0
    y = []
    for datas in our_mongo_database_compressed: 
        y.append(datas)
        if(x > 100):
            break
        x+=1
    #print(y)
    return str(y)
```

and my react function looks like

```
this.setState({
            disaster: event.target.value
        })

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/refresh_data', [this.state.disaster])
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(JSON.parse(response.data));
        })
        
    }
```

I keep getting a " Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2" and I just want the data to be sent to react

Comment: You have square brackets around `this.state.disaster` in the `axios.post` call, try curly braces.

Comment: Nah that sends just fine and displays it in python, no issues there

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and I want anyone who has this problem in the future to be able to see this.

```
for datas in our_mongo_database_compressed: 
        y.append(datas)
```

This creates an array of dictionaries. so y[0]["user"]["location"] would be how you'd get an element from this array.

With that in mind we need to change this array to a JSON String which is a data type that you use to transfer between flask and react so you'd return

```
return json.dumps(y)
```

Now you might think this means that you got a string in React when you write

```
JSON.parse(response.data)
```

NO. That would be too easy, you have a response object that secretly a string. So you'd need to change the response object into a string with JSON stringify

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data))
```

Now you have your json in react